# pstatus_t no found in procfs.h (LINUX)

Tags: c, linux

I am reading the /proc/PID/status file using my C program and I want to use the pstatus_t struct to directly read the values from the file into this struct. However, my compiler is showing that this file is not present in the procfs.h. 
I have checked few examples on internet where they are using the same header file but in my case, it is not working.

Comment: It is a kernel structure, so you need kernel headers and appropriate defines to use them, or define it manually. Using this structure binds your executable to particular kernel version (+-).

Comment: I am using the Debian machine and latest version of gcc

Comment: isn't it defined in procfs.h ? I have seen some example on internet where they are using the same header file

Comment: It really depends. You need to check your headers by yourself. The structure can be defined but protected by macro, for example. For kernel structures, it can be something like `#define _STRUCTURED_PROC 1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "reading /proc/PID/status", I'm assuming that you are running in userspace (as opposed to in the kernel). In this case, the pstatus_t structure is worthless to you. Most files under /proc, including status, are a text-formatted representation of the kernel data structures. There is no way to directly get the binary contents of a kernel pstatus_t structure.