# How to read /proc/pid/stats in C

Tags: linux

I need to write a C / C++ code to get the following information from the status of a process:

> struct timespec utime; // user time
>
> struct timespec stime; // system time
>
> size_t dsize; // data size
>
> size_t shmsize; // shared memory size (created)
>
> size_t vshmsize; // shared memory size (used)

Currently I have this implemented for Solaris, but how do I get this information in Red Hat, is there any API to do this?

On Solaris I can read the process status to a struct, like this:

```
static int readPStat(pid_t processid, pstatus_t *ret)
{
  char pfile[256];
  int  stat=-1;

  sprintf(pfile,"/proc/%d/status", processid);
  stat =open(pfile,O_RDONLY))
  read( stat, ret, sizeof(pstatus_t)) );
  .......
}

int getProcessInfo (  )
{
  pid_t     processid;
  pstatus_t procStat;
  int       dSize;
  .......
  readPStat(processid, &procStat) 
  .......

  dSize = psinfo.pr_rssize;
}
```

I tried doing some research but couldn't find a definitive answer on how to do this in Red Hat.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how to write C code for this purpose, or about where to find the particular data you want?

Comment: If you're asking about where to find the data, [the Linux manual page for the proc filesystem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) has a pretty complete reference.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, what I need in fact is to write C code to get this information when the application is running on Red Hat, on Solaris it is possible to read the process status to a struct.

Comment: Sorry, but if I understand you correctly then you know where to find the data you want, and you know how it is formatted.  What, then, is preventing you from reading it from the appropriate proc file and storing it however you want?  Please understand that although we exist to help programmers, we are not a coding service -- we answer *specific*, narrow questions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, let me try to make it more specific then, haha.
I was wondering if there is a struct similar in Red Hat to the pstatus_t defined in sys/procfs.h on Solaris, I thought about creating my own struct to store the information but I just wasn`t sure if there was something similar.
I am kinda newbie in Linux programming, so if I there is no pre-defined struct like Solaris and I can read and store the information however I want, then I can close this question.

Comment: Woah, @AndréPenedo, "is there a structure?" is a completely different question from "How to read?" and "Is there an API?".  If that's really what you've been trying to ask then I'm actually a bit shocked.  To my knowledge, however, no, there is no such structure defined for userspace use.  And if there were, it wouldn't be any more help to you than a structure you define yourself -- see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21817824/2402272.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, ok then I'll define my own structure, thanks for your help!